# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm just trying to execute a MySQL file within MariaDB, but it gives me the following error: `ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 14: Can't create table roundcube.calendars (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

That's the SQL query: https://pastebin.com/4FBA30JM
Unfortunately I can't post it here since it kinda messes up the formatting.

Comment: Please share your code here instead of sending us to an external link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your calendars table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calendars` (
  `calendar_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `showalarms` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY(`calendar_id`),
  INDEX `user_name_idx` (`user_id`, `name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_calendars_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `users`(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I tested this out in a sandbox and the statement is fine. There's nothing wrong with it.

However, I don't see a `users` table in your linked code sample. Before you can create a table with a foreign key, the following must be true:

- The referenced table (`users` in your case) must exist.
- The referenced table must use the InnoDB storage engine.
- The referenced column (`user_id`) must exist in the table.
- The referenced column must have exactly the same data type as the foreign key column that references it. In your case, this is `INT UNSIGNED` (The integer length argument (10) is optional and may be different in the two tables).
- The referenced column must be the leftmost column of a KEY. Ideally it should be the entire PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY, to be compatible with standard SQL. Technically, InnoDB also allows foreign keys to reference non-unique keys, but this is discouraged.

So you must have a table at least like the following already existing in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I had to create this table in my sandbox before your calendars table definition would work.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I've rechecked my database and found the users table, however it has a prefix, so I'll probably have to replace the tables in the whole script.